# VBA Find value in row using wildcard

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have tried to make a loop (I'm very new to the VBA) that check for the word "Apple" in column A. Column A contains fruit names. When "Apple" is found, then the code is copying range "H2:S2" to Column G and the corresponding row value in Column A.

But the code will not run when the search criteria part is changed to wildcard (My goal is to include rows where the word Applecake exist).

```
lookupVal = "Apple" 'Works
lookupVal = "*Apple*" 'Nothing happens
```

How should I adjust the code below so it runs with wildcard or maybe there are a better solution than this code states to achieve the result?

Full code:

```
Sub CopypasteValues()
    Dim i, j, lastrowA As Long
    Dim lookupVal As String

    'finds the last row in Column A
    lastrowA = Sheets("Dataset").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'loop over values in Sheet "Dataset"
    For i = 1 To lastrowA 
        lookupVal = "Apple" 'Define search critera

        For j = 1 To lastrowA
            currVal = Sheets("Dataset").Cells(j, "A")
            If lookupVal = currVal Then
                ValueCopy = Range("G2:S2").Copy 'Range to copy
                Sheets("Dataset").Cells(j, "G") = Range("G" & j).PasteSpecial 
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Side Note: Make sure you specify a type for **every** variable. With `Dim i, j, lastrowA As Long` you only declare the last as `Long` the first 2 remain `Variant`: Use `Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrowA As Long` instead to declare all 3 of the type `Long`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Like` operator:

```
If currVal Like lookupVal Then
```

So, if `lookupVal` was `"*Apple*"` and `currVal` was `"Aren't Apples nice to eat"`, the test would be `True`.

---

You might also need to use

```
If LCase$(currVal) Like LCase$(lookupVal) Then
```

if you want to avoid case-sensitivity problems.

---

You could also consider using `Find` (with a `LookAt:=xlPart` or `LookAt:=xlWhole` parameter as required), rather than doing a cell-by-cell comparison.  But it would depend on exactly what your requirements are as to whether that was a feasible solution.

Comment: Many thanks!!!! Works perfect for me.
And a big extra thank you for pointing out the case-sensitivity problem, good to know. I haven't encounter it for now, but might do it.

Comment: I have tried to use the `Find`, but at my stage of knowledge is still to hard and I couldn't make it work properly.

Comment: @Wiz - for a beginner, and while you don't have much data that could cause speed issues, using the `Like` is definitely going to be the "easiest" option.

Comment: Yea, I think that too. I looping through approx 700 rows and only 1 column. Is still way faster than doing it manually. But I see your point with large matrices or/and a lot more rows.